# Why is my code different in http-server than what I have in my file?

Tags: javascript, httpserver

This is what my code looks like in my script.js file:

```
let defenseTable = document.querySelector('#home-stats');
```

When I run my code in localhost using http-server it gives an error saying defenseTable is not defined. When I go to debug the code line says

`defenseTable = document.querySelector("#home-stats");`

it removes my let variable declaration. Why? The code works fine by the way if I run it without http-server.

Comment: Do you have #home-stats element on the page? This error say that you don't: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined

Comment: It's really hard to believe the declaration would be dropped. To solve this, we really need a [mcve]. Are you sure you haven't scrolled past the few first columns when reading the source?

Comment: You use `http-server` as if it's a product but the tag refers to *any* http server. Which one are you using?

Comment: Is the http request cached?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have http-server also configured with some other type of build step which is transpiling your code in some strange way, which is the only reasonable explanation for a variable declaration being dropped in this manner.